# Use other deployment IP in YAML deployment configuration

Tags: kubernetes

I'm doing a prototype where one service depends on an availability of other. Scenario:

- Service A is assumed to be already available in a local network. It was either deployed by K8S or manually (or even a managed one provided by AWS etc.).
- Service B depends on environment variable `SERVICE_A_IP` and won't start without it. It's treated as a black box and can't be modified.

I want to pass Service A IP to Service B through K8S YAML configuration file. Perfect syntax for this occasion:

```
...
env:
  - name: SERVICE_A_IP
    valueFrom:
      k8sDeployment:
        name: service_a
        key: deploymentIP
...
```

During the prototyping stage Service A is an another K8S deployment but it might not be so in a production environment. Thus I need to decouple from `SERVICE_A_SERVICE_IP` that will be available to Service B (given it's deployed after Service A). I'm not into DNS discovery as well as it would require container modification which is far from a perfect solution.

If I would do it manually with `kubectl` (or with a shell script) it would be like the following:

```
$ kubectl run service_a --image=service_a:latest --port=8080
$ kubectl expose deployment service_a
$ SERVICE_A_IP="$(kubectl describe service service_a | \
    grep IP: | \
    cut -f2 -d ':' | \
    xargs)"
$ kubectl run service_b --image=service_b:latest --port=8080 \
    --env="SERVICE_A_IP=${SERVICE_A_IP}"
```

It works. Though I want to do the same using YAML configuration without injecting `SERVICE_A_IP` into configuration file with shell (basically modifying the file).

Is there any way to do so? Please take the above setting as set in stone.

**UPDATE**

Not the best way though still:

```
$ kubectl create -f service_a.yml
deployment "service_a" created
service "service_a" created
$ SERVICE_A_IP="$(kubectl describe service service_a | \
    grep IP: | \
    cut -f2 -d ':' | \
    xargs)"
$ kubectl create configmap service_a_meta \
    --from-literal="SERVICE_A_IP=${SERVICE_A_IP}"
```

And then in `service_b.yml`:

```
...
env:
  - name: SERVICE_A_IP
    valueFrom:
      configMapKeyRef:
        name: service_a_meta
        key: SERVICE_A_IP
...
```

That will work but still involves some shell and generally feels way too hax.

Comment: Question: can't you use a hostname to refer to service A instead of an IP address?

Comment: @whites11 Hostname would work I guess. I can set it for a service in K8S configuration file, can't I? If so then yep, would work like a charm.

Comment: Every service in kubernetes has it's own (internal) dns name. It depends on how your cluster is configured, but usually it is `<servicename>.<namespace>.svc.cluster.local` .

Comment: @whites11 I was looking into this at some point but somehow abandoned this idea altogether. I use `minikube` locally currently. Thanks for pointing me back to this approach. I'll see what I can do.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [attach handlers to lifecycle events](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/attach-handler-lifecycle-event/) for update your environment variables on start.

Here is an example:

`apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: appB
spec:
  containers:
  - name: appB
    image: nginx
    lifecycle:
      postStart:
        exec:
          command: ["/bin/sh", "-c", "export SERVICE_B_IP=$(host <SERVICE_B>.<SERVICE_B_NAMESPACE>.svc.cluster.local)"]`

Kubernetes will run `preStart` script each time when pod with your appB container is starting right in appB container before execution of the main application.

But, because of [that description](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/containers/container-lifecycle-hooks/#container-hooks):

> **PostStart**
>
> This hook executes immediately after a container is created. However, there is no guarantee that the hook will execute before the container ENTRYPOINT. No parameters are passed to the handler.

You need to add some `sleep` for your main app before the real start just to be sure that hook will be finished before application will be started.

Comment: Well, that's a possible approach. Thanks for sharing!